# role is coming Undefine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cookies

```
exports.authorizeRoles = (...Roles)=>{
  
  return (req,res,next)=>{
    if(!Roles.includes(req.user.role)){
        next(new ErrorHander(`Role ${req.user.role} is not allowed to accsess this resource`,403))
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

the above is my code for getting the role and authorize them to do some specific operation
but i am getting this type of error in my postman at the time of API testing

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')"
}
```

Comment: Try logging the content of `req`, you may find that this is being called when there is no `req.user`

Comment: yeah i am trying to access this after logging the user

Comment: The error message seems to be indicating that req.user is null.  `auhtorizeRoles` returns a 3-arity function, where is that function called?